# jquery tooltip display

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

Based in this example http://jsfiddle.net/Nb3uW/30/ how can make it to show each link the tooltip? It show last link only.
Where tr is topright, tl=topleft, bl=bottomleft, br=bottomright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your markup didn't give clear idea about in which manner you wanted to show your tooltip.But here is something i did to ensure that the changes to the original markup,css and script are minimal http://jsfiddle.net/raynesax/Nb3uW/32/